# Nothing happens when trying to validate fields with Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to apply validation to my model class but it doesn't work, it simply ignores and registers the values ​​in the database even if it is null or empty.
I'm using Lombok

My user model:

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;


@NotNull
@NotBlank

private String nome;  

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private BigDecimal incomeMonthly;

@Convert(converter = RiskEnumConverter.class)
private RiskEnum risk; 

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

My address model:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
   
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private Integer number; 
   
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String neighborhood;
    
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String postalCode; 
    
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String state;
   
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String city;
```

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> save(@Valid @RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        User saveUser = this.userService.save(cliente);
        publisher.publishEvent(new ResourceCreatedEvent(this, response, saveUser.getId()));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(saveUser);
    }
```

POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to annotate your rest controller with @Validated

Comment: @DanielJacob 
keeps registering in the database and returning 201

Comment: Only adding an API won't do anything, you also need an implementation of that API like `hibernate-validator` without that, nothing will happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum is this done through annotations?

Comment: As @M. Deinum underllines it, you miss a dependency in your project. When using only `validation-api` you provide interfaces without implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of the validation API.

So, you need to add this to your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.13.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

You can use the version according to your need.

If you think of exploring a bit about it, check out this [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation).

Answer (score 0):

From the code above it looks like you are missing an exception handler that would catch the validation failures. the handler allows you to specify how the validation failures should be handled in your application. [This article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation) from the baeldung website shows how the exception handler can be set up.

In my projects I would typically set up an error handling class with methods for each kind of error, e.g.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
        public ValidationFailureResponse validationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
            BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
            final List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

            return new ValidationFailureResponse((FieldError[])(fieldErrors.toArray(new FieldError[fieldErrors.size()])));
         }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments you will need a validation implementation to make this work. From the Baeldung article the following mvn dependency is mentioned:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Validation works also without an exception handler. He is just missing an implementation .